# Implementing 2 menus with Sidr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, sidebar

I would use two status menu using Sidr (http://www.berriart.com/sidr/). 
By default it opens with a class width 260px, but would like to work with another div with a larger opening. How can I use two menus into one file?

Answer (score 0):

i tried sidr-right, and simply i just restyle this 2 elements when I need it 210px wide:

```
    .sidr.right {
        right: -210px;
    }

    .sidr {
        width: 210px;   
    }
```